# How to add beanshell code in any config element to update user property?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

1.we can add beanshell pre / post processor, but I want for all request.
2. Also, beanshell / BSF sampler can be used, but while exection, it will be displayed in report.

So what I want is to have a place where i can write code and can use as "config element".

Is there any way for that ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no scriptable "config element", so you have a few options:

1. Create a new scriptable config element as a JMeter plug-in
2. Use a script inside one of the fields inside another config element. For example:

   [image]
   Here I defined a *User Defined Variables* configuration element, and specified a script as a value of a variable.
3. Use BeanShell/BSF PreProcessor on Thread Group level:

   [image]

   It will run at the beginning of every iteration for every thread. Or similarly BeanShell/BSF PostProcessor on Thread Group level will run after each iteration on each thread.

Comment: I tried option 2, but it didn't worked. Option 3 will execute that code for each request and will impact the execution time. For option 1, is there any such plugin available ? Jmeter's documentation are very poor for this.